# CSS and JS clashing for Layout View and Rendered View in ASP.NET MVC-4

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-modal

[**ASP.NET MVC-4 (RAZOR) App Model**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmBXp.png)
I am creating a web application in ASP.NET using MVC-4 Architecture. I have planned to deploy various modules within my app. I have fixed a LAYOUT in SHARED folder containing Bootstrap,CSS,JQuery,JS. The structure of my app is as follows:

` //Header Begins

Rendering Bootsrap, JQuery, styles & scripts for the **main Layout of MyApp (UI)**, defined in Bundles File.

// Header Ends

// Body Begins

render view(); // The view being rendered has different Styles, Scripts but have common functions name. As a result of which the CSS and JS is clashing.

// Body Ends

// Footer Begins

` // Footer Ends

I want my DASHBOARD MODULE VIEW to be rendered within the body of my layout. After implementing it, the Styles, Scripts are clashing, the page being unresponsive. Someone even told me to use **important!** attribute, and another told me to rename the classes for Dashboard. Its a cumbersome process, I want to get rid of such tedious condition. Please Help!!

Comment: Well, can you post you code so that we can help?

Comment: Dear Krishna, thanks for your feedback..Please check if this helps. [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PmBXp.png)

Comment: Why dont you use inspect tools to see what errors you have (in client) like for example in chrome you can right click -> inspect element -> console and check your errors

Comment: After I am adding @{Layout=null;} to the DASHBOARD view file, the dashboard is working excellent, but now the header and footer of my main layout are wiped up from the dashboard page. However,I need that too.

Comment: Add the code... the simplest solution sounds like resolving the name clash...this would be done ones... and should be quick to do....It may be cumbersome process but is better design and only has to be one once.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @Seabizkit . Is this a last option? Though its a complex process to change the class names, but is it possible in case of bootstrap?  I have different modules in my app, that shares a fixed layout. I would add the code soon.

Comment: @Narayan to make the right call, need to see what is conflicting. This kind of thing wouldn't take that long... which implies that you are either not too familiar with the progress/ways or there really is a wack load of css. tip Never rename styles in lib css (bootstrap)... only your own... by overriding the styles in a a custom css file. If you want both then by the sounds of it you need to change the actual html files... even if there were 50... that wouldn't take that long, Find something common in the html and go through each one and change it as desired.